# Want to open Leaflet / React Leaflet popup to the right side of MAP in React Typescript

Tags: reactjs, leaflet, react-leaflet, react-tsx, leaflet.markercluster

I want to open the leaflet/React Leaflet map popup to the right side of the Map but it is opening near the marker or otherwise I want to open my custom Popup to the right side of the map after click on the marker.
Version I use -
"react": "^18.2.0",
"react-leaflet": "^3.2.5",
"react-leaflet-markercluster": "^3.0.0-rc1",
"leaflet": "^1.7.1",
"leaflet.markercluster": "^1.5.3",
"typescript": "^4.9.3"

```
<MarkerClusterGroup {...markerclusterOptions} >{locations.map((location: IMapDetails, i: number) => (
                    <Marker key={i} position={[location.latitude, location.longitude]} icon={greenIcon} >
                        <Popup onOpen={handleOpenDetails}>
                            {location.trip.itvMap.vehicle?.regNum}
                            <DriverDetailDialog open={openDetails} onClose={handleCloseDetails} tripDetails={location} />
                        </Popup>
                    </Marker>
                ))}</MarkerClusterGroup >`
```

My code to open Popup I want to display "DriverDetailDialog" to show on the right side of the Map but it opening near the marker

I want to display "DriverDetailDialog" to show on the right side of the Map but it opening near the marker.
I tried it with leaflet ane React leaflet package also.But it is not showing to the right side of the screen

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.